# Resize h1 under 768px in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I have an h1 header inside a row with font awesome mark quotes to the left and right of it. I want it to be resized when the screen goes under 768px. So i have:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 10pt;
    }
  }

.header,
h1 {
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20pt;
  }
.fa-quote-left {
  position: relative;
  left: -20px;
  top: 15px;
  }
fa-quote-right {
  position: relative;
  left: -90px;
  top: 15px;
  }
```

```html
 <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <header class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <h1> <span class="fa fa-quote-left fa-flip-vertical"></span> This is an h1 and i want it to be resized, but it won't.agagagkeifjiejfiefjeifjeifjeifje <span class="fa fa-quote-right> <h1>
          </div>
          </header>
```

But in my browser it won't resize even after the media query.

Comment: How do you want to appear when the window resizes, because I can see it getting resized.

Comment: it is getting resized however my mark quotes break so i want the font to be smaller instead of breaking the words in the h1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define the media query after the default options. The way you have it now the media query gets overwritten, no matter the screen size.

Comment: i have another media query for the navbar in my custom.css. The h1 media query is above all...where do i need to define it?

Comment: Make sure that your media query is the last defined CSS rule to change the h1 font.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using pt for font-size, try using em.